# How to optimize Shopify Website Core Web Vitals?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am facing issues to optimize website speed for mobile version. I have already fixed things that were possible but due to apps I am facing issues. I can't optimise code that is in the Apps. I already checked all details from Google's page speed insight tool.

How to fix this in less time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have a look at this guide: https://performance.shopify.com/pages/techniques-for-optimizing-web-performance